# Rails 3 and ActiveAdmin. Filter is displaying Objects not the company name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I have a list of customers but on the filter section on the right column, I get a list like this `#<Customer0X0B500>` in the select menu. How can I display the company_name attribute of Customer instead?

Comment: can you add more code to the question ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Figured it out, thanks!

`filter :customer, :collection => proc {(Customer.all).map{|c| [c.company_name, c.id]}}`

Comment: In which file do I have to put this? Doesn't work in the model

Comment: In the app/admin/your_model_name.rb ;)

Comment: also `filter :customer, collection: proc { Customer.pluck(:company_name, :id)}` should save you quite some time.

Answer (score 6):

i'm not sure I understand you but probably you should define to_s method inside your Customer class e.g.

```
class Customer

  def to_s
    self.company_name
  end

end
```

it would be easier if you shared some code

Comment: Worked for me!!

Answer (score 4):

```
class Customer

  def display_name
    self.company_name
  end

end
```

Defining display_name instead of to_s works better...

- to_s may be called automatically by other objects.
- display_name only affects ActiveAdmin

You can also define:

```
show :title => :display_name
```

This will make your company_name appear as the title on the view pages instead of Company #x.

Comment: For association columns we make an educated guess on what to display by
calling the following methods in the following order:

    :display_name, :full_name, :name, :username, :login, :title, :email, :to_s

This can be customized in config/initializers/active_admin.rb.

Answer (score 1):

To make ActiveAdmin display select menu properly try in Model.rb:-

alias_attribute :name, :category_name